# CSS table and max-width in Chrome not working

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, css-tables

This is my CSS code;

```
#wrap {
    width:50em;
    max-width: 94%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#fff;  
}

#head {
    width:50em;
    height:10em;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
}

#css-table { 
    display: table; 
    margin: 1em auto;
    position: relative;
    width:50em;
    max-width: 100%;            
}

#css-table .col { 
    display: table-cell; 
    width: 20em;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#css-table .col:nth-child(even) { 
    background: #fff;
}

#css-table .col:nth-child(odd) { 
    background: #fff;
    border-right: 4px double #b5b5b5;
}
```

And my HTML code;

```
<div id="cont">
    <div id="css-table">
        <div class="col">123</div>
        <div class="col">123</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I scale the Firefox window, the table scales fine even down to 300px width viewport...just like I want to. But in Chrome, the table looks normal only when the viewport is wider than 50em. If I narrow the Chrome window, the table bleeds out on the right side of the wrap.

Is there a reason why is Chrome doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a div and give it a styling to display block and a max width. You may use traditional `<table>` and give it a styling of 100% width.

Answer (score 27):

Technically Chrome is following the rules because **max-width should only apply to block elements**.

From MSDN docs:

> The min-width/max-width attributes apply to floating and absolutely
>   positioned block and inline-block elements, as well as some intrinsic
>   controls. They do not apply to non-replaced inline elements, such as
>   table rows and row/column groups. (A "replaced" element has intrinsic
>   dimensions, such as an img or textArea.)

The table (or in your case display:table) should technically not work or be supported. FF apparently obeys it fine, but you'll probably need to come up with another solution, either removing the *display:table* or the *max-width*.

[max-width property](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/max-width)

[MSDN Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530811(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks! display table works in Chrome perfectly :)

Answer (score 27):

The solution I found was using `table-layout: fixed` and `width: 100%`

Comment: This is what I do  these days, but by doing this  I need to set width again.anyway to let old css work which don't have fixed min and max width?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to use a mixin(SASS) to fix the issue.

```
 @mixin clearfix {
   &::after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
   }
 }
```