# max-width in an HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table

Given below an HTML table.

```css
.panelgrid {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<table class="panelgrid" rules="all" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Value</td>
        <td>Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The style given makes word-wrap occur, when the text entered into the table cells exceeds the specified `max-width: 500px;` property.

What does not happen is when the width of the text is smaller than the `max-width` property, the table should automatically fit according to the width of the text which does not happen.

The table width stays at 500px even though in case, the text length is smaller than 500px.

How can it be achieved so that the table automatically shrinks, when the text length is smaller than the specified length (500px in this case)?

---

Currently the above CSS is just like,

```
.panelgrid {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 500px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: So you don't want to remove `width:100%` in the top example? That will cause it to stretch...

Comment: Either including or excluding `width:100%`. Anyway, it should function as said.

Answer (score 2):

you can set a table width of auto, and keep your max width of 500px. Then set word-break to break-all

```
width:auto;
max-width:500px;
word-break:break-all;
```

[demo is here](http://jsfiddle.net/pow48tt0/4).

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word` does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: setting a max-width for the cell will solve the word-wrap issue: .panelgrid td{max-width:400px;} for example

Comment: While I did not give it a try on IE 10+, IE versions lower than 10 do not behave properly.

Comment: i tested it in ie 10 and 9, and it seems to be working as expected.

Comment: ive updated the fiddle, found your prob! use word-break instead of word-wrap jsfiddle.net/pow48tt0/4

Answer (score 1):

Change your css to this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/3b5aa3qq/

```
.panelgrid td{
    max-width: 400px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Remove the length of the "Long" word to see it shrink. You can also give it a padding to look more beautiful

Comment: Yeah you're right! I just left there because it was already there. thanks

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word;` does not happen on Internet Explorer 8.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a containing block element (table is not a block element) and use max-width on that to constrain the width.

```
<div style="max-width:500px;">
   <table>
      ...
   </table>
</div>
```

See also this SO answer
[**min-width/max-width on no-block elements**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12233052/2247427)

Comment: That gives a horizontal scroll bar relative to the table, when the table content exceeds the width specified.

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle of exactly what you have so I can play with it?

Comment: Hmm unfortunately this may not be possible. I see the dilemma. You might have to fix the column width on the left to be able to do this. Unfortunately word-break only works on table-layout:fixed however the nature of having it fixed means equal width for all columns (see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using max-width or width try using min-width

Comment: Using `min-width`, the table grows horizontally to fit the entire screen (on Internet Explorer 8).

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers are correct.  Using `max-width` will make the `div` be as small as possible, while still being large enough to fit whatever content you put into it.  Using `width` will make the `div` always be that specific pixel size, no matter the content that it holds.

Answer (score 0):

```
.panelgrid {
    table-layout: fixed;
    max-width: 500px;

    -ms-word-break: break-all;
    word-break: break-all;

    // Non standard for webkit
    word-break: break-word;

    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
}
```

Try this. Worked for me on jsfiddle.